# Repository not found in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, repository, azure-repos

My project repository is available & user level permission is set as basic. Group user permission set all allow but another user not see repository & showing this message.

"It is possible the repository did exist at one point, but your project administrator renamed or deleted it. Please ensure that the repository exists and that you have access."

Admin users can see the repository & can pull & push.
[image]

Comment: Hi, any update on this issue, have your check my answer? does it answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce  your issue:

[image]

Only needs two steps:

1, the teams permission be able to read project level information.

[image]

2, Give read permission of the specific repo to the specific team.

[image]

If still unable to view the repo, please check the specific user permission of the repo, if it denied, team permission will not work.

The above is the minimum required permissions. If you need more, add them based on your requirements.