# Azure DevOps - cannot create pipline - no matching repositories found

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have an Azure ADO project TerraformAppService which has a repository TerraformAppService.

[image]

I click Pipelines -> Create Pipeline -> Azure Repos Git

[image]

For some reason Azure is unable to see the repo in the same project, although it can see all the repos in the other projects. The logged in user is the one that created the repo and uploaded the code.

[image]

I've encountered this several times now and each time after just randomly clicking around and trying different things it has started working after a while. But I'm sick of wasting an hour on this every time it happens.

Does anyone know the solution to this?

Comment: Could you check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73605729/2347999 ?

Comment: Not related. I can view and access the repo, but the dialog to create a pipeline fails to list it.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer but a workaround.

If I navigate to the repo and click 'Set up build', then the 'Create Pipeline' wizard runs with the first couple of steps already completed which then allows me to complete the creation of the pipeline.

I'd still like to see this fixed though.